# Why does Hadoop on Windows trying to connect 0.0.0.0:10020 (unsuccessfully)?

Tags: windows, hadoop

I have installed `Hadoop` on `Windows` [according to this artile](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10) and now am able to run test application `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-X.Y.Z.jar`.

Unfortunately, when I am starting full-scale application, it starts to access some strange address `0.0.0.0:10020`. Have changed my DFS config to `<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0</value>` but this didn't help.

Exception is following:

```
[Thread-14] INFO org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchControlledJob - Job status available at: http://lagrangian:8088/proxy/application_1525212500911_0002/
[Thread-14] ERROR org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor - Pipeline failed due to exception
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From lagrangian/169.254.105.43 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.CrunchJobHooks$CompletionHook.handleMultiPaths(CrunchJobHooks.java:92)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.CrunchJobHooks$CompletionHook.run(CrunchJobHooks.java:79)
        at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchControlledJob.checkRunningState(CrunchControlledJob.java:288)
        at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchControlledJob.checkState(CrunchControlledJob.java:299)
        at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchJobControl.checkRunningJobs(CrunchJobControl.java:193)
        at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchJobControl.pollJobStatusAndStartNewOnes(CrunchJobControl.java:313)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor.monitorLoop(MRExecutor.java:131)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor.access$000(MRExecutor.java:58)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor$1.run(MRExecutor.java:90)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From lagrangian/169.254.105.43 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:320)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.isSuccessful(Job.java:616)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.CrunchJobHooks$CompletionHook.handleMultiPaths(CrunchJobHooks.java:84)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From lagrangian/169.254.105.43 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:801)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getJobReport(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getJobReport(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:133)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:325)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
        ... 28 more
```

I read it is probably related with `Job History Server`, but I am not sure, how to run it on `Windows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the JobHistory server isn't started. You can run it using

```
mapred historyserver
```

Should be very similar between Windows and Linux. Check log output and `jps` to verify it's running.

Your service addresses should ideally be a hostname (but not localhost), while 0.0.0.0 will make them listen on all addresses

Comment: Timeline and History Server aren't the same thing. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Differences-between-HistoryServer-and-Yarn-TimeLine-server-td4132626.html